# Redirect page after 30 minutes of inactivity in XPages

Tags: xpages

I would like a page to redirect to a login page automatically after 30 minutes of inactivity.  The session is set to expire after 30 min, and nothing will work on the open page anyway.  If user refreshs or navigates elsewhere it does redirect to login, but not if the page is left open and unattended.  I work for a bank and this would give them warm fuzzies, as it is how most banking apps work these days.

I would prefer a serverside solution, but open to client side. Reason for this is they have lots of restrictions on browser operations on the client which is IE 9.

I was really surprised that I couldn't find someone who did this before, believe me I looked.  I don't mind building this, but first wanted to see if anyone else has already built something similar.  Any advice on best practices is also appreciated.

Comment: This might help. http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=C71D8C6CDA625F0E852578CB00667E09 But AFAIR, you should not be using xhrGet, instead the XSP related method call.

Comment: Still looking for answers that include code examples :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a meta tag in your [page header](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) - that would be the simplest solution. It could be computed. Drawback: a partial refresh wouldn't reset the counter. So you would need to manipulate it in each call

Option two: add a JS timer on page load, that checks after 30 minutes a Ajax call. If the call fails with Not authorized refresh the entire page - it then will go to whatever login is configured (don't try to hardcode a redirect page)

There is no server side option since all communication is issued by a client/browser. A server side code can't make the browser do anything if it didn't ask. (the modern protocols that would support that don't exist in your environment

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I will give these a try. Enjoy the top of the world.

Comment: I went with option 2.  I decided to skip the ajax call to test whether session is still valid, and opted to make it timed to run a minute after session expires.  Whenever user interacts I reset the timer.  This fits my need better, but your suggestion is probably the best all-purpose solution.  Thanks again